# Dropbox app for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, dropbox

Can anyone give me link of some tutorial or source code for app like standard Dropbox app. Having root directory shown first and then upon click on folders show contents of that folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the github link that will help you.

[link1](https://github.com/schwa/dropbox-iphone-sdk)

[link2](https://github.com/ohminteractive/dropbox-sdk-ios)